# Mostrar apenas um registro de cada ID

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

Eu tenho uma tabela `Clientes` e uma `ClientesTel`. Eu preciso apresentar uma lista onde apareça o `Código do Cliente, Nome, Telefone e o email`, mas pela estrutura eu posso ter varios telefones. Segue o SQL que estou tentando modificar:

```
SELECT ClientesTel.id, Clientes.nome, ClientesTel.telefone, ClientesTel.email
    FROM ClientesTel INNER JOIN Clientes ON ClientesTel.id = Clientes.id
```

Mas não consigo fazer esse filtro. Ele sempre mostra dobrado.

Estou utilizando SQL Server 2014 e ASP.Net.

Comment: O que está dobrado? Mostre como estão seus dados, o resultado obtido e o esperado. Pra mim não tem nada duplicado: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/07114/1 Se bem que o correto seria outra *query*: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/07114/2. Aí tem um cliente dobrado para poder aparecer os 2 telefones. Isto está errado? Não deveria estar.

Comment: (15) 99135-9999 alber@gmail.com         3 Albert Brum
(15) 99173-9999 shad@gmail.com         1 Fabio Zanardo
(15) 99695-9999                                  1 Fabio Zanardo

Não gostaria que exibisse 2 registros do Fabio

Comment: Isto não ajuda em nada. Não vejo nada duplicado aí. Mas se considera que está, explique melhor. Você viu o que eu montei? Se não conseguir clarificar o problema a pergunta terá que ser fechada.

Comment: Então.. deixa ver se eu consigo passar o que preciso... No seu segundo exemplo, aparece João 2 vezes pois ele tem 2 telefones cadastrados... Numa listagem de Clientes com telefone, vc contaria como se tivesse 4 clientes cadastrados... e não 3 como realmente é... se for seguir a logica, se um cliente tiver 5 ou 6 telefones, vc acabará tendo uma listagem duplicada 6 vezes com o mesmo cliente...

Não sei se conseguir ser claro nessa explicação... é como se eu pegasse cada cliente e mostrasse apenas 1 telefone de cada cliente.

Comment: Eu desisto, eu mostrei para você que não tem duplicação, você não consegue **mostrar** a duplicação, não consigo ajudar assim. Eu mostrei as duas formas, uma que só mostra um fone por cliente e a outra que mostra todos fones, aí duplica, mas foi pedido p/ listar todos os fones, é fisicamente impossível mostrar 2 telefones do mesmo cliente sem repetir a não ser mude a estrutura do banco de dados.

Comment: Então... Na primeira Consulta, ao meu ver João tem 2 telefones, estou certo? Se sim, o segundo telefone do João, aparece para José... há uma mistura dos IDs...

Comment: Não, não sei onde você está vendo isto.

Comment: Veja se ficou mais facil de identificar agora...

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6704/1

Comment: Não, aí você está duplicando manualmente a informação. No meu há 2 informações diferentes, no seu há duas informações iguais. Se o dado está errado, não há código que dê jeito. E esta *query* que você está usando está errada, a outra é que está certa. Eu falei isto no 1o. comentário. Esta *query* compara banana com laranja. E isto não faz sentido. Esta está certa http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/07114/2

Comment: Então.. se vc reparar na primeira string SQL que vc me mandou (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/07114/1) e a minha (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6704/1) eu apenas mudei as informações dos campos pra mostrar que há um erro na primeira sql q vc me enviou... Mas tudo bem eu vou dar um jeito aqui... Obrigado pela ajuda..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu entendi sua pergunta e o select para sua resposta é este, correto?

```
WITH  Tels as(
SELECT  ClientesTel.id, 
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
   (PARTITION BY Clientes.nome ORDER BY ClientesTel.id)
  as number,
  Clientes.nome, ClientesTel.telefone, ClientesTel.email
    FROM Clientes
    INNER JOIN ClientesTel
    ON Clientes.id = ClientesTel.Clientes_id)
 select id, nome, telefone, email from tels
 where number = 1
```

Veja como fica o resultado [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4af02/1) é o retorno esperado certo?

João possui 2(dois) telefones porém você necessite que apareça apenas um retorno, correto? No caso o retorno é sempre o primeiro telefone do Cliente.

PARTITION BY:
   Essa função serve para contar quantas ocorrências de um determinado dado aconteceu em um campo, no caso utilizei o Nome, logo estou contando quantas ocorrências teve com o mesmo nome, no caso de joão terá ocorrência 1 e 2 para o campo "number", logo após faço um select para pegar todos os dados que estejam com o campo "number" = 1 que será todos os Clientes que possuírem no mínimo 1 telefone ignorando assim as ocorrências subsequentes. Espero que a explicação esteja clara.